# Wrong processing of GetDIBits() builder c++

Tags: c++builder

I use `GetDIBits()` to retrieve the bits of bitmap and copies them into a buffer.  The function doesn't fail (the result is different to NULL), but I get wrong height of bitmap and erroneous buffer.

This is a part of my code:

```
HDC hdcMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hDC); // (hDC = hDC = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps): i get it in WM_Paint)
int l_uiWidth = 400;
int l_uiHeight = 120;
HBITMAP hbmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDC, l_uiWidth, l_uiHeight);
HGDIOBJ oldhbmp = SelectObject(hdcMemDC,hbmp);
BITMAPINFO   bi;
bi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
bi.bmiHeader.biWidth = l_uiWidth;
bi.bmiHeader.biHeight = l_uiHeight;
bi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
bi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 8;
bi.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
bi.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = 0;
bi.bmiHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
bi.bmiHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
bi.bmiHeader.biClrUsed = 256;
bi.bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0;
BYTE *l_ImagePDM = new BYTE[l_uiWidth * l_uiHeight];
GetDIBits(hdcMemDC,hbmp,0,l_uiHeight,l_Image,&bi,DIB_RGB_COLORS);
```

Please Help me!
What's wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 0):

You have not drawn anything on the bitmap that you are querying the bits for.  `CreateCompatibleBitmap()` does not make a copy of the pixels of the source `HDC`.  It merely allocates an `HBITMAP` that is compatible with the specified `HDC`, which then allows you to select the `HBITMAP` into that `HDC`.  But you still have to draw something onto the bitmap to make its content meaningful before you can then query its bits.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain more.

Comment: In the code you showed, you are creating a blank bitmap and then retrieving its bits. What do you want the code to do instead?

Comment: I want to copy what it is drawn in a window (from its handle, i get the device context)

Comment: I guess that's a problem of memory when allocating memory to the buffer.
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144879(v=vs.85).aspx)

Any idea please ?

Comment: The HDC returned by `BeginPaint()` is only valid within `WM_PAINT`. Drawi on that HDC first, then you can `BitBlt()` it onto your memory HDC before calling `GetDIBits()`. Outside of `WM_PAINT`, use `GetDC()` or `GetWindowDC()` instead, then `BitBlt()` and `GetBIBits()` as needed.

Comment: Do you have an example please ?

Comment: I fellow this example but I get at the end an empty buffer (white image)

Answer (score 0):

When you use C++ Builder you can use `Graphics` unit for processing graphics.

Example of copying something from window:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    // Create a bitmap
    Graphics::TBitmap* bit = new Graphics::TBitmap();
    bit->PixelFormat = pf24bit;
    bit->HandleType = bmDIB;
    bit->Width = 200;
    bit->Height = 200; // or bit->SetSize(200, 200) - newer versions C++ Builder

    // Copy something from this Form (from window)
    bit->Canvas->CopyRect(TRect(0, 0, 200, 200), this->Canvas, TRect(0, 0, 200, 200));

    // Do something with bitmap data
    RGBTRIPLE* line;
    for (int i = 0; i < bit->Height; i++)
    {
        // Get memory address from line i
        line = (RGBTRIPLE*) bit->ScanLine[i];

        // Change 5'th pixel
        line[5].rgbtRed = 255;
    }

    // Get whole bitmap memory. Bitmap data are stored upside down and size of each row is rounded
    // up to a multiple of 4 bytes.
    unsigned char* bitmem = (unsigned char*)(bit->ScanLine[ bit->Height-1 ]);
    //...

    // Draw bitmap on Form
    Canvas->Draw(0, 200, bit);

    delete bit;
}
```

When you have device context you can use TCanvas like this:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    // Create device context
    HDC hdc = GetDC(this->Handle); // or GetWindowDC - whole window with frame

    // Create canvas and associate device context
    TCanvas* canv = new TCanvas();
    canv->Handle = hdc;

    // Create a bitmap
    Graphics::TBitmap* bit = new Graphics::TBitmap();
    bit->PixelFormat = pf24bit;
    bit->HandleType = bmDIB;
    bit->Width = this->ClientWidth;
    bit->Height = this->ClientHeight; // or bit->SetSize(w, h) - newer versions C++ Builder

    // Copy window content
    TRect r(0, 0, this->ClientWidth, this->ClientHeight);
    bit->Canvas->CopyRect(r, canv, r);   //  USEING TCanvas

    // Release context and delete canvas
    ReleaseDC(this->Handle, hdc);
    delete canv;

    // Do something with the bitmap
    bit->SaveToFile("screenshot.bmp");
    delete bit;
}
```

You can also use TCanvas for device context from BeginPaint:

```
canv->Handle = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
```